# how to blur the bottom layer when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

The top bar of my app is fixed. When the main page scrolls, the top bar will cover it. How to get the blurring effect of the main page when the top bar is on top of it?

twitter.com has this effect

Comment: just make your top bar background color to transparent like rgba(0,0,0,0.5) then add filter: blur(4px) or adjust to your desired value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweeter uses [`backdrop-filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter)

```css
.navbar
{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1 class="navbar">My navbar</h1>
  <h3>some text</h3>
  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/IlhDxQVsR17dwwER5xYZJej867KrdSx0K5eyRP2RFP4eQJMD2pi0ZGBhrMOcajBUP9M54lpmIr90JecPUFGPaRe3sDZ82RvHBSw1rw-YJvQs7J8K3g=w1024-h1024-n-l50-sg-rj">
</div>
```